# Is it faster to call a method as I initialise an object or hold it as a variable and call the method on that

Tags: java, object

Assuming that there is a class ClassA which gives a value that I need through non-static method.

In case when I just need a value from an instance of the ClassA, 
I guess there are two possible choices.

```
double value =0 ; // The value I actually need, the object is just transitory

1) ClassA a = new ClassA (hogehoge);
   value = a.getValue();

2) value = new ClassA(hogehoge).getValue();
```

I know there maybe an advantage or disadvantage for both.
but generally speaking what is the difference between them?

in case 2), memory use is smaller than 1) or....

Comment: `new ClassA(hogehoge).getValue;` is compilation error !

Comment: Keep always in mind that there is so much optimzation done in the compiler and in the virtual machine so that you will hardly measure any difference in this example.

Answer (score 12):

Actually this two piece of code will have a small difference:

```
***** Class1.p
       8: invokespecial #4                  // Method ClassA."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      11: astore_3
      12: aload_3
      13: invokevirtual #5                  // Method ClassA.getValue:()D
      16: dstore_1
      17: dload_1
      18: dreturn
}
***** CLASS2.P
       8: invokespecial #4                  // Method ClassA."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      11: invokevirtual #5                  // Method ClassA.getValue:()D
      14: dstore_1
      15: dload_1
      16: dreturn
}
*****
```

I.e. we see here two additional instructions for variant #1:

```
      11: astore_3
      12: aload_3
```

But it seems, that after jvm warms-up these instructions will be optimized (eliminated) and it will be no difference at all.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the optimization which will lead to no difference at all.

Comment: hmm ok Im not familiar with optimization by jvm or compilers...but anyway thank you very much I understand

Answer (score 10):

The only difference is that in 2nd case, the object you created will be eligible for *garbage collection* immediately after that statement, as you don't have any reference to that object. You have an *unnamed* object there.

While in 1st case, since you have a reference to an object, you can access that object and its member later on also. So, it won't be eligible for *garbage collection*, <strike>[until it goes out of scope]</strike> (This statement, as discussed in the below comments, I'm still confused about. Will confirm this once I get the behind the scene concept), or there are no more reference created to that object, using reference assignment, or any other method.

---

BTW, in your 2nd case, you forgot a parenthesis there. It should be:

```
value = new ClassA(hogehoge).getValue();
```

Comment: It should be generally noted, that in most cases a programmer (especially a novice one) should not worry about such micro-optimizations at all.

Comment: @AdamDyga : Yea you are right about the generally not caring for micro-optimizations but the OP asks for what is the difference between the two, which is faster and what takes more memory.

Comment: @KensukeKonishi. You're welcome :) You can upvote the answer by clicking the voting button on the left hand side of the answer. Also, if the answer was useful, you can mark it as accepted, by clicking the arrow below the voting button.

Comment: @KensukeKonishi. Ah! Did you downvoted the answer by mistake?

Comment: This is incorrect. In the first case, if there are no further uses of the variable `a`, then the object becomes eligible for garbage collection immediately after the call to `getValue`. Eligibility for garbage collection is not governed by the existence of in-scope variables, but by whether the object "can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread". See [§12.6.1 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1).

Comment: @RohitJain I hope not. but anyway I clicked voting (for UP) now

Comment: @TomAnderson. Well, as the first statement states - `A reachable object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread.`, it is clear that we can still access the object created in the first case, further down in the same scope. Doesn't matter whether we are using it or not, it is still accessible. This is what makes it in-eligible for GC.

Comment: @TomAnderson. I take an unreachable object as the one, to which we have no way to get access to.

Comment: @RohitJain If the variable is never accessed again, even if we remain in the same scope, the JLS specifies that collection is allowed. The JIT may even inline the constructor call anyways. Hotspot in particular can perform some advanced escape analysis on variables such as this.

Comment: @TomG. May be I'm not quite able to grab that section of JLS linked in previous comments. May be I'll take a look at it later. Certainly will learn new thing today, if it goes that way. Thanks :)

Comment: @RohitJain: A continuing computation can only do something if it contains code to do it. Computers don't have free will, after all! If a method contains no code which accesses a particular variable, then it cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 4):

You can view the bytecode for yourself:

```
double value = 0;
ClassA a = new ClassA();
value = a.getValue();
value = new ClassA().getValue();
```

becomes

```
   0: dconst_0      
   1: dstore_1                          // *double value = 0;*
   2: new           #2                  // class ClassA
   5: dup           
   6: invokespecial #3                  // Method ClassA."<init>":()V
   9: astore_3      
  10: aload_3       
  11: invokevirtual #4                  // Method ClassA.getValue:()D
  14: dstore_1      
  15: new           #2                  // class ClassA
  18: dup           
  19: invokespecial #3                  // Method ClassA."<init>":()V
  22: invokevirtual #4                  // Method ClassA.getValue:()D
  25: dstore_1      
  26: return
```

Overall, there is no real difference between these two approaches in terms of speed, and you shouldn't worry about micro-optimizations like that.

Comment: Thank you very much. now, I will remember i should not care about micro optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

Difference is negligible. The first case keeps reference `a` (4 bytes) to ClassA until it is garbage collected (for example when you return from your method).

Comment: This may be true if the code is interpreted, but as soon as it is compiled to native code by the JIT, it is overwhelmingly likely that the variable will optimised away, and there will be no difference between the two versions.

Answer (score 1):

Not much difference performance wise.

The main difference is that with the in-line version, the instance created is available for garbage collection as soon as the line finishes executing, and possibly *before* finishing, depending on the JVM.

Although creating an instance is fairly cheap, consider using a static method - so creating the instance and garbage collecting it can be avoided:

```
public static double getValue(HogeHoge hogehoge) {
    // some impl
}
```

Comment: The objects become available for garbage collection at the same times - see my [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425917/is-it-faster-to-call-a-method-as-i-initialise-an-object-or-hold-it-as-a-variable#comment25310768_17425997).

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to don't care about these micro optimizations and to focus more on readability of your source code.

I'd choose the solution that makes it easier to understand whats going on, even if it requires one more reference to be allocated.

In principle the version without the intermediate variable should, of course, save the memory required by the reference, which is negligible, and it should make available the object for garbage collector as soon as the operation is executed instead of when the reference goes out of the scope.

Also, note that that pieces of code *may* turn into the very same byte-code due to compiler optimization, which is another reason why you should not care about it.

Comment: Note that there isn't really any difference in garbage collectibility either - see my [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425917/is-it-faster-to-call-a-method-as-i-initialise-an-object-or-hold-it-as-a-variable#comment25310768_17425997).

Answer (score 1):

Fun fact (a little bit OT): Under .NET, an object can actually be garbage collected before going out of scope - even while one of its methods is still executing (see sample code below or live demo at: http://rextester.com/WTKSYE61526 - prints out "False False" when ran under Release configuration and outside the debugger).

What does this tell us?
Well - a future version / different implementation of the JVM might implement a similar behavior (it's possible that there are even JVMs out there which already do).

Theoretically speaking (assuming a garbage collected environment), the two options can be considered equal. They might only be executed a little bit different during execution because of an implementation detail in the JVM (if they are not optimized as Andremoniy mentioned). And implementation details are subject to change.

So don't bother with the differences and go for the more readable one.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.Foo();

        new Program().Foo();
    }

    public void Foo() 
    {
        WeakReference r = new WeakReference(this);

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();

        Console.WriteLine(r.IsAlive);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if any current JVM will collect the object while the method is still executing, but JVMs are already allowed to collect an object as soon as it becomes unused, even there are references to it still in scope (see my [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425917/is-it-faster-to-call-a-method-as-i-initialise-an-object-or-hold-it-as-a-variable#comment25310768_17425997)), and i believe they already do so. Your prophecy of what a future version might do has already come to pass!